# recurrning billing system

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an application where recurring billing is involved. I have few questions before starting this, please help..

When Any Member signups and accept to pay for next 11 months? How should I process this with php? should I store this is another my sql table or in a  single row? What php function should I get to get next 11 months in case I want to store those in my sql table?

How should i run cronjob? Check monthly_due table and get all member whose members are pending for current month?

Comment: Where is your code? What is your problem? What you have you tried so far?

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel i have some confusion, and need help to start with.

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly store your subscriptions separately from your members info. Not only will this allow you a complete record of all subscriptions but will also help if you need to have variable length subscriptions. Your tables structure might be something like this:

```
subscriptions
-------------
subscription_id  integer
member_id        integer
start_date       date
end_date         date
date_paid        datetime
```

Then you can use SQL directly to find subscriptions about to expire etc. So to find any subscriptions due to expire within the next seven days you could have something like

```
SELECT
  member_id,
  MAX(end_date) as expires_date
FROM
  subscriptions
GROUP BY
  member_id
HAVING
  expires_date < DATE_ADD( CURDATE() INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

Comment: thanks, you have got an idea, actually customer would pay us for next 11 months from sign up date. so i should even store their payment, and how to get users whose payments are falling for this month.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do this

Subscriptions database table
In the table contain a date for when the subscription expires (date field)

In php calculate the date like this:

```
$expire = date('Y-m-d',time() + (86400 * 365));
// 86400 = 24 hrs * 365 = 1 year
```

I would then run a cron script that selects subscriptions where the date field is 30 days eminent, send a renewal email

Then block subscriptions that are like 10 days overdue

That's in short how i would approach it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you store the member's subscription expiry date in your table, which is calculated as (date of payment + 11 months).

To list members which are due for renewal, just list members where renewal_date lies between (today's date) and (today's date + 30 days)

Comment: great suggestion, thanks. is my sql enough to add (date of payment + 11 months) ie. `NOW()+11`

Comment: You could do your date manipulations either in your MySQL query or in your PHP code. In general, my preference is to do it in code.