# recurring system my sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a membership system where user will pay for next 11 months from date joined on, my db structure as follows...

members table

```
| id | name   | email         | joined_on  | expire_on  |
+-------------+---------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | tester | test@test.com | 2012-01-09 | 2012-12-09 |
+----+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

I really need yours help with following...

I will run a cron job monthly/weekly, i would like to send payment reminder to users for monthly installment, what mysql query/php function should i use?

how to ensure if somebody didn't miss any payment, or how can i mark payment?  thanks...

Comment: How is this different from [recurrning billing system](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8755945) except that there is now a table schema?

Comment: @Pekka i need some suggestions.

Comment: The thing is that this is pretty much basic PHP/mySQL that is covered by most tutorials out there. Are you familiar with those basics? If not, I would consider working through such a tutorial first.

Comment: @Pekka yes, i just need some suggestions from experts here.

Comment: @seoppc 1st suggestion is don't try to open an equally vague question when the first one is closed.  2nd suggestion is to check out the php and mysql tutorials and then come back with specific questions.  It looks like you want someone to write it for you and this isn't the place for that.

Comment: @Robert no i don't want that, i needed direction, but thanks if you taking it wrong way.

Comment: @seoppc well it's hard not to take as you want the work done when you haven't posted a specific question.  Is your question "how to ensure you don't miss a payment"? yes that is a question but the one before that "what mysql query/php function should i use?" tells me your looking for someone to write the code for you.  And you should reference your first question and give more detail as to why you asked it a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another table called payments which has
 - `id` of payment
 - `userid` of user 
 - `date` they last paid
 - `length` of payment

Then, to check when a user's set to expire,

`SELECT date+length as expy FROM payments WHERE userid = $userid ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`

Store dates & lengths as unix time (number of seconds).  If time > expy then their subscription is expired.

Comment: why are we using 'length' field?

Comment: So that users can pay for 11 months, or pay for 1 month, or pay for an arbitrary amount of time - when they pay for 11 months, you just enter one field with a length of `11*30*24*60*60` (11 months, 30 days/month, 24 hrs/day, 60 mins/hr, 60 secs/min)